# How move a View Cell to its own XAML file in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a list view containing a context action and I want to disable it under certain circumstances.

An answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35974/disable-specific-cells-contextactions-in-listview) suggests moving the view cell to it's own XAML file and using OnBindingContextChanged to enable or disable individual context actions.

I tried moving the View Cell to a file which looks like this:

```
<forms:ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:forms="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:Fraedom.UserControls;assembly=Fraedom"
            x:Class="Fraedom.UserControls.ApprovalTemplate">

<forms:ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <forms:MenuItem Text="Approve" />
</forms:ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

but get an error when I reference it from the list view like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <DataTemplate>
      <dataTemplates:ApprovalTemplate></dataTemplates:ApprovalTemplate>
    </DataTemplate>

</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I also tried moving the Data template instead of the view cell, and tried wrapping both in a content view (which you can't as neither are a view).

Any ideas?

Here is the error:

```
System.NullReferenceExceptionObject reference not set to an instance of an object
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.UpdateGlobalContext (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view) [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewCellRenderer.GetCellCore (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context) [0x00058] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.CellRenderer.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context) [0x00045] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.CellFactory.GetCell (Xamarin.Forms.Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context, Xamarin.Forms.View view) [0x00023] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.GetView (Int32 position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent) [0x00193] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetView_ILandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, Int32 position, IntPtr native_convertView, IntPtr native_parent) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.cs:509 
      at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:1c8a63a2-474e-436f-9097-a2380578ec91 (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

First, you don't need to alias the main Forms xml namespace when you've already established it as the default namespace for the document. Therefore, you can drop `xmlns:forms="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"` from the root element, and also all occurrences of the `forms:` prefix.

Second, you are missing the closing tag for your custom ViewCell xaml. That's probably your error, as it looks like the cell inflator process is where the crash is taking place.

I think I would probably put this cell template into a resource dictionary though instead of defining a custom class for it. You can still attach event handlers to templates, even when defined as a dictionary resource entry. Of course that assumes you are reusing the template. If you are only using it in this one ListView then I don't really see why you would break it out into another file.